# Do i need to define relationship in SQL Server database if i am using EF and Linq

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

I am working on a asp.net mvc project and using Linq for all my data related operations. In such cases, do I need to define relationship in the SQL Server database ??

I am using Entity framework and Linq so I think it doesn't matter if I create an E-R diagram(i.e defining relationship) or not.

Comment: Are you asking if you need foreign keys in database in order to have relationships in entity model?

Comment: You don't necessarily need an ER diagramm - but you **most definitely need** foreign keys to define your relationships in the database!!

Comment: @marc_s , not the ER diagramm necessarily but the foreign contraints. I mean if i am using EF code first with an existing database. Is there a need to define relationship in the database. For example, In code-first, we create the database on fly and in that database there are no foriegn contraints defined

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay: **Y E S** !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By 'define relationship' I assume you mean 'Foreign key constraints'. It is always advisable to define constraints in order to maintain data integrity. You should also consider that the database for your project could probably be used by other applications in the future which might be based on other technologies than EF.

Comment: I like your answer as it goes in depth. But, you agree that with EF, there is no need to explicitly defining foreign contraints in tables ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have relations in DB they will automatically be imported in your EF Model but you always have an option to create the associations manually in the EF Designer if you don't have relations in DB.

See [How to manually add association in Entity Framework](http://www.overroot.com/blog/?p=330)